EF Load Related Entities Over a List Collection of Entities
EF Core's documentation gives a simple example about how to load a related collection to a single entity.
var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
// Load the posts related to a given blog.
_context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();

But what if I want to load that related collection on a collection of entities?  My code is passed in a list of entities, and I need to load the related entities after the fact.  If I had control over where the data was queried, I would have used an .Include, but that is not an option.
i.e. I want my code to accomplish the following, but obviously all in one DB query rather than one at a time...
function LoadBlogPosts(List<Blog> blogs)
{
    foreach (var blog in blogs)
        context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();
}

How do I accomplish this with a single query?
I've thought of doing something like this:
function LoadBlogPosts(List<Blog> blogs)
{
    var blogIds = blogs.Select(b => b.Id);
    var allPosts = context.Posts.Where(p => blogIds.Contains(p.BlogId).ToLookup(p => p.BlogId);
    foreach (var blog in blogs)
        blog.Posts = allPosts[blog.Id];
}

But won't that cause the context to think I've made changes, causing problems later if I call .SaveChanges?
EDIT: I have one project w/ Lazy Loading and one w/o, so I'm always interested in how Lazy Loading affects questions like this.  Sorry I didn't think to mention that up-front!

Load Blogs again using their Ids context.Blogs.Where(b => blogs.Select(sb => cb.Id).Contains(b.Id)).Include(b => b.Posts).ToList(). Child collections should be initialised automatically.

The EF docs use .Include to eagerly load related entities, not Load. To load a blog and posts, use context.Blogs.Include(b=>b.Posts).Find(1). To get specific blogs by ID, context.Blogs.Include(b=>b.Posts).Where(b=>blogIds.Contains(b.Id)). The list can easily come from another collection, eg var blogIds=blogs.Select(b=>b.Id).ToList();

I'm trying to avoiding the DB perf hit of querying the Blogs table again.  I want to only hit the Posts table.  This is obviously a much simpler example of my real-world data and why I can't do what you two are both suggesting.

@pbristow, Then just load Posts context.Posts.Where(p => blogs.Select(sb => cb.Id).Contains(p.BlogId)).ToList() it should be enoung if blogs are tracked entities.

Svyatoslav's correct. If your passed in entities are still tracked by the DbContext then all you need to do is load the related entities desired from the DbContext. You do not set the blog.Posts collection, just load the entities. When you visit the blog entities their Posts collection will be populated.

Thank you for clarifying that @StevePy. I thought I had direct experience that contradicted that, so I wasn't drawing the assumed connection that others were only implying.  I think it's possible Lazy Loading causes this to not work, which unfort my project uses for legacy reasons, though I've been slowly working to remove it.

I have confirmed with SQL Profiler that this works with Lazy Loading OFF but does not if it's ON.  I suspect the reasons are the same reasons I didn't ever think of trying this answer.  With Lazy Loading off, EF is willing to say "this is the data I've got, though I don't know if it's complete."  The code isn't designed to compare the query to the FK, of course, so it just attaches the entities whether complete or not.  Lazy Loading OTOH can instead query for it to ensure completeness, and does so.

Finally, I just confirmed that even doing what's in the last code block and setting the Posts collection direction to each Blog does NOT stop Lazy Loading from fetching the Posts from the DB when you get the blog.Posts property.  I am shocked and baffled by this last finding.  Checking the change tracker both with and without Lazy Loading shows that it does not consider setting the collection like this to be a tracked change.
